# Xcode 6.3 update cause ide to frozen and need force quit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I just updated Xcode to new 6.3 version and I have problem with it. Everytime when I go from Interface Builder with my MainStoryboard to any code file I get loading progress and application is frozen. I can't do anything and I must use Force quit to quit Xcode and run again but I get same problem. It is with just one of my app and the others are okay and Xcode is working fine. I am not sure what is the problem. Problem app has many views in storyboard but other my apps too. It's in swift but I tried some other example projects and no problem.

I really want to fix this problem so I take first few lines from info after force quit:

```
Date/Time:       2015-04-10 14:10:12 +0200
OS Version:      10.10.3 (Build 14D131)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  21

Command:         Xcode
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Version:         6.3 (7569)
Build Version:   2
Project Name:    IDEFrameworks
Source Version:  7569000000000000
Parent:          launchd [1]
PID:             594

Event:           hang
Duration:        1.10s (process was unresponsive for 320 seconds before sampling)
Steps:           12 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  MacBookPro10,2
Active cpus:     4

Fan speed:       2162 rpm

--------------------------------------------------
Timeline format: stacks are sorted chronologically
Use -i and -heavy to re-report with count sorting
--------------------------------------------------

Heaviest stack for the main thread of the target process:
  12  start + 1 (libdyld.dylib + 13769) [0x7fff8b86b5c9]
  12  NSApplicationMain + 1832 (AppKit + 13140) [0x7fff9947f354]
  12  -[NSApplication run] + 594 (AppKit + 551923) [0x7fff99502bf3]
  12  ??? (<2D862ACB-D0E0-3846-A777-5B2C3034C408> + 1318362) [0x110276dda]
  12  -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346 (AppKit + 593768) [0x7fff9950cf68]
  12  _DPSNextEvent + 978 (AppKit + 596411) [0x7fff9950d9bb]
  12  _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71 (HIToolbox + 205099) [0x7fff910e812b]
  12  ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431 (HIToolbox + 205546) [0x7fff910e82ea]
  12  RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235 (HIToolbox + 206191) [0x7fff910e856f]
  12  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296 (CoreFoundation + 465880) [0x7fff8f2d7bd8]
  12  __CFRunLoopRun + 2024 (CoreFoundation + 468488) [0x7fff8f2d8608]
  12  __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 301 (CoreFoundation + 1221949) [0x7fff8f39053d]
  12  __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1059 (CoreFoundation + 749427) [0x7fff8f31cf73]
  12  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20 (CoreFoundation + 750308) [0x7fff8f31d2e4]
  12  __NSFireDelayedPerform + 364 (Foundation + 308251) [0x7fff9883b41b]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 844193) [0x110e221a1]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 845367) [0x110e22637]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 847265) [0x110e22da1]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 2337454) [0x110f8eaae]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 847466) [0x110e22e6a]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 847855) [0x110e22fef]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 848146) [0x110e23112]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 848562) [0x110e232b2]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 850427) [0x110e239fb]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 2115290) [0x110f586da]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 571839) [0x110ddf9bf]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 361406) [0x110dac3be]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 361754) [0x110dac51a]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 2108389) [0x110f56be5]
  12  ??? (<053704CD-4B33-3C59-915F-0979F48157F0> + 2101698) [0x110f551c2]
  12  -[NSView removeFromSuperviewWithoutNeedingDisplay] + 38 (AppKit + 1359529) [0x7fff995c7ea9]
  12  -[NSView removeFromSuperview] + 435 (AppKit + 438399) [0x7fff994e707f]
  12  -[NSView _setSuperview:] + 675 (AppKit + 259352) [0x7fff994bb518]
  12  ??? (<2D862ACB-D0E0-3846-A777-5B2C3034C408> + 108788) [0x11014f8f4]
  12  ??? (<2D862ACB-D0E0-3846-A777-5B2C3034C408> + 289845) [0x11017bc35]
  12  ??? (<2D862ACB-D0E0-3846-A777-5B2C3034C408> + 2318676) [0x11036b154]
  12  ??? (<F77F04E0-7640-3115-8245-6052DFF052E0> + 3633286) [0x11a70c086]
  12  ??? (<F77F04E0-7640-3115-8245-6052DFF052E0> + 56886) [0x11a3a2e36]
  12  ??? (<F77F04E0-7640-3115-8245-6052DFF052E0> + 1194480) [0x11a4b89f0]
  12  ??? (<F77F04E0-7640-3115-8245-6052DFF052E0> + 1193538) [0x11a4b8642]
  12  ??? (<F77F04E0-7640-3115-8245-6052DFF052E0> + 1199009) [0x11a4b9ba1]
  12  ??? (<F77F04E0-7640-3115-8245-6052DFF052E0> + 1344856) [0x11a4dd558]
  12  ??? (<0AC21504-55BC-3F11-BE13-5E0FEC1759C1> + 209920) [0x11fdd4400]
  12  ??? (<0AC21504-55BC-3F11-BE13-5E0FEC1759C1> + 249917) [0x11fdde03d]
  12  ??? (<0AC21504-55BC-3F11-BE13-5E0FEC1759C1> + 246203) [0x11fddd1bb]
  12  ??? (<F77F04E0-7640-3115-8245-6052DFF052E0> + 868598) [0x11a4690f6]
  12  ??? (<0AC21504-55BC-3F11-BE13-5E0FEC1759C1> + 246373) [0x11fddd265]
  12  ??? (<0AC21504-55BC-3F11-BE13-5E0FEC1759C1> + 250364) [0x11fdde1fc]
  12  ??? (<F77F04E0-7640-3115-8245-6052DFF052E0> + 2629753) [0x11a617079]
  12  _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 597 (libdispatch.dylib + 46423) [0x7fff8ebdf557]
  12  semaphore_wait_trap + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 70938) [0x7fff935de51a]
 *12  semaphore_wait_continue + 0 (kernel + 1357760) [0xffffff800034b7c0]


Process:         Xcode [594]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Architecture:    x86_64
Parent:          launchd [1]
UID:             501
Sudden Term:     Dirty
Task size:       71539 pages
CPU Time:        0.005s
Note:            Unresponsive for 320 seconds before sampling
Note:            2 idle work queue threads omitted

  Thread 0x6341       DispatchQueue 1     12 samples (1-12)   priority 47
  <frontmost, thread QoS user interactive, boosted, received importance donation from WindowServer [142], IO policy important>
  12  start + 1 (libdyld.dylib + 13769) [0x7fff8b86b5c9] 1-12
    12  NSApplicationMain + 1832 (AppKit + 13140) [0x7fff9947f354] 1-12
      12  -[NSApplication run] + 594 (AppKit + 551923) [0x7fff99502bf3] 1-12
        12  ??? (<2D862ACB-D0E0-3846-A777-5B2C3034C408> + 1318362) [0x110276dda] 1-12
          12  -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346 (AppKit + 593768) [0x7fff9950cf68] 1-12
            12  _DPSNextEvent + 978 (AppKit + 596411) [0x7fff9950d9bb] 1-12
              12  _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71 (HIToolbox + 205099) [0x7fff910e812b] 1-12
                12  ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431 (HIToolbox + 205546) [0x7fff910e82ea] 1-12
                  12  RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235 (HIToolbox + 206191) [0x7fff910e856f] 1-12
                    12  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296 (CoreFoundation + 465880) [0x7fff8f2d7bd8] 1-12
                      12  __CFRunLoopRun + 2024 (CoreFoundation + 468488) [0x7fff8f2d8608] 1-12
                        12  __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 301 (CoreFoundation + 1221949) [0x7fff8f39053d] 1-12
                          12  __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1059 (CoreFoundation + 749427) [0x7fff8f31cf73] 1-12
                            12  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20 (CoreFoundation + 750308)
```

Is there a way how to fix this? Or maybe some trick that help me? Thanks

Comment: it's a bug, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544738/xcode-6-3-freezes-hangs-after-opening-xib-file/29559808#29559808)

Comment: Removing the plugins solved it for me. Plugins were not working anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Carrl it really help me. Apple should really fix all problems with custom controls in IB.

Comment: @LiborZapletal haha, that's true~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Carrl I found another [question with similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544738/xcode-6-3-freezes-hangs-after-opening-xib-file) (difference is that my Xcode froze when I tried to get from IB) and it helps me. As in other question I was really using custom views with @IBDesignable tag and in some cases I was using custom fonts.

So my solution:

First I remove folder xcuserdata in Project.xcworkspace and then I was able to run project and search for files that has @IBDesignable mark and I removed it. Now it looks that It works.

Comment: Can you duplicate @picciano 's Radar? This will help motivate Apple to fix this. I've asked him to duplicate on OpenRadar http://openradar.appspot.com/ so everyone can see it.

Comment: Also, there are others like myself who have similar problems with XCode 6.3 hanging with storyboards that don't have IBDesignable, but do have custom fonts.

Comment: We have the same issue with @IBDesignable