# Xcode editor tool becomes hang when I click on XIB file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm Reviewing the existing code received from client side and started looking at Xcode Version 6.3 (6D570).I could see all classes and supported files but whenever I click on any xibs editor gets hang and I'm not able to open any files or click anywhere in the Xcode editor. its keep on loading. If I quit the editor it prompts the alert "do you want to send report to apple - click Ignore / Report". henceforth, I can use editor only restart my macbook. Can anyone tell me the reason behind?

**Fixes In Detail**: As said I used IBInspectable and IB_DESIGNABLE in my custom view but no luck for me Even updating to 6.3.2 and I faced the same issue, then un-installed my Xcode Editor and migrated to the recent version from app store made me fixed the issue that I've faced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6.3 freezes/hangs after opening XIB file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544738/xcode-6-3-freezes-hangs-after-opening-xib-file)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Xcode 6.3. It is fixed in 6.3.1 or later.

See more information over at [Xcode 6.3 freezes/hangs after opening XIB file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544738/xcode-6-3-freezes-hangs-after-opening-xib-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to force quit the xcode editor then it always ask you for report to apple. I have same issue in my iMac that time i have 4GB RAM but after that i increased my RAM Size to 8GB and now its working perfectly, So if your mac-book RAM is 4GB then increase RAM size.

Comment: If so, then how could I open xibs from my other projects?

Comment: No if you can able to open XIB from other apps then its not editor or RAM Issue. its may be the project XIB issue.

Comment: Yes, Same issue. I have a mac book with the same configuration and I could open and see all the files from that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your xib files could be corrupt. Try opening them as source code and pasting them in an XML lint tool http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by updated Xcode version 6.3 to 6.4. Working perfect.Seems existing code has developed via latest version of Xcode Editor. Thanks