# Create multiple custom UILabels in Interface Builder with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have a `nib/xib` file with several `Labels`. Each label should obviously have a different text, but should all look the same. I therefore create a (very simple) `CustomLabel` class that inherits from UILabel:

```
import UIKit

class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2.0
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    }
}
```

I then click on each label in Interface Builder and set each custom class to this "CustomLabel", but nothing is changing when I compile.

How do I correctly create and link custom elements?

Comment: Try marking the class as `@IBDesignable`

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't change in the storyboard or when you run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IB\_DESIGNABLE, IBInspectable -- Interface builder does not update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674111/ib-designable-ibinspectable-interface-builder-does-not-update)

Comment: I can try, but I heard that IB_DESIGNABLE and IBInspectable is quite buggy in XCode 6.3. What I mean however is that it doesn't update when run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was that I didn't call `self.layer.masksToBounds = true` ([Giving UIView rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners), thus the rounded corner was not showing. I still don't understand why `self.layer.backgroundColor` doesn't have any effect though.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the init, parts of the view might not be loaded yet.
You might want to do your view setup in

```
override public func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2.0
    self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Like @yairsz said, awakeFromNib is the place to put that code. However, per Apple's documentation (albeit AppKit documentation), "You should call the super implementation of awakeFromNib only if you know for certain that your superclass provides an implementation." So if your super class doesn't provide it, don't call super.awakFromNib(). And you may also not need it to be public, but that's for you to decide for your specific needs.