# Dynamic User Defined Runtime Attributes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I set a User Defined Runtime Attribute in Xcode to a value associated with the object? For example, I want to set the `layer.cornerRadius` of a view to always be `size.width / 2` to round the corners. I know that if I know the size of the view, I can set it to a constant like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this dynamically? I have tried replacing `150` with `size.width / 2` but I get the following warning:

> The value “size.width / 2” is invalid.
>
> Please provide a valid value.

Comment: You would have to this in `viewDidLoad()` or `didLayoutSubviews()`, as far as I know.

Comment: the corresponding property type of NSNumber:   Number – NSNumber * or any numeric scalar, e.g. NSInteger.  May check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089193/what-is-key-path-in-user-defined-runtime-attributes#37851027

Answer (score 0):

You should add under the viewDidLoad() method, the following:

```
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = yourView.frame.width / 2
```