# How to implement the "didset of swift" in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, didset

Swift (from the book 《iOS Animations by Tutorials:Chapter 12》 released by http://www.raywenderlich.com/):

```
let photoLayer = CALayer()

@IBInspectable
  var image: UIImage! {
    didSet {
      photoLayer.contents = image.CGImage
    }
}
```

How can I implement the above syntax in objective-c?
I know only to set the property of photoLayer and image like below:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CALayer *photoLayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBInspectable UIImage *image;
```

But i do not know how to implement `didset{...}` parts using objective-c syntax, please help!

Comment: check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674111/ib-designable-ibinspectable-interface-builder-does-not-update

Comment: please not this will crash in swift if image is nil.

Comment: in objc calling a nil object works, but in swift it could be `photoLayer.contents = image != nil ? image.CGImage : nil`

Comment: it looks you look for the `-setImage:` method.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

override the setter and implement the setter yourself.

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if (_image != image) {
        _image = image;
        photoLayer.contents = image.CGImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift needs special language features for this, because of its static nature, one cannot subclass at runtime.

In Objective-C this is not necessary, so you have no language feature for this. You can use [key-value observation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

But if the observing instance is the instance whose property changed, you can do it with subclassing as mentioned by @Daij-Djan. (Basically this is what you do in Swift.) Additionally in Objective-C you have the ability to observe the properties of a different instance of a different class.